# XeLaTex: Input longtable and compiling process freezes

Tags: xetex, longtable, texmaker

I have quite a long document containing different chapters that are all included via `\input{chapter}`. Although I have used this document for weeks already, yesterday the compiling process would just freeze and not even show any problems that occurred. The problem seems to be with a input file that just contains a longtable. Without this one, it compiles successfully.

I use the following commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract=true,a4paper,toc=bib]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{longtable} %tabellen die länger als eine ganze seite sind
```

The input file that contains the longtable is:

```
{\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{l c c c c c}
\caption{... \label{descstat1}}\\
\toprule\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}}
 &\textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} &  \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N} \\ 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table \thetable, continued}
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on following page...}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\textit{Dependent variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2  & a & b & c & d & e\\
3  & a & b & c & d & e\\
4  & a & b & c & d & e\\
5  & a & b & c & d & e\\
6  & a & b & c & d & e\\
7  & a & b & c & d & e\\
8  & a & b & c & d & e\\
9  & a & b & c & d & e\\
10  & a & b & c & d & e\\
11  & a & b & c & d & e\\
12  & a & b & c & d & e\\
13  & a & b & c & d & e\\
14  & a & b & c & d & e\\
15  & a & b & c & d & e\\
\textit{Control variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2  & a & b & c & d & e\\
3  & a & b & c & d & e\\
4  & a & b & c & d & e\\
5  & a & b & c & d & e\\
6  & a & b & c & d & e\\
7  & a & b & c & d & e\\
8  & a & b & c & d & e\\
9  & a & b & c & d & e\\
10  & a & b & c & d & e\\
11  & a & b & c & d & e\\
12  & a & b & c & d & e\\
13  & a & b & c & d & e\\
14  & a & b & c & d & e\\
15  & a & b & c & d & e\\
\caption*{\footnotesize ...}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}}
```

I also just updated my texmaker to the newest version available.

What can be reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is simply a forgotten `\\` before `\midrule` (in your "Table ... continued" part).

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract=true,a4paper,toc=bib]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{longtable} %tabellen die länger als eine ganze seite sind
\begin{document}
The input file that contains the longtable is:
{\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{l c c c c c}
\caption{... \label{descstat1}}\\
\toprule\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}}
 &\textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} &  \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N} \\ 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on following page...}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\textit{Dependent variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2  & a & b & c & d & e\\
3  & a & b & c & d & e\\
4  & a & b & c & d & e\\
5  & a & b & c & d & e\\
6  & a & b & c & d & e\\
7  & a & b & c & d & e\\
8  & a & b & c & d & e\\
9  & a & b & c & d & e\\
10  & a & b & c & d & e\\
11  & a & b & c & d & e\\
12  & a & b & c & d & e\\
13  & a & b & c & d & e\\
14  & a & b & c & d & e\\
15  & a & b & c & d & e\\
\textit{Control variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2  & a & b & c & d & e\\
3  & a & b & c & d & e\\
4  & a & b & c & d & e\\
5  & a & b & c & d & e\\
6  & a & b & c & d & e\\
7  & a & b & c & d & e\\
8  & a & b & c & d & e\\
9  & a & b & c & d & e\\
10  & a & b & c & d & e\\
11  & a & b & c & d & e\\
12  & a & b & c & d & e\\
13  & a & b & c & d & e\\
14  & a & b & c & d & e\\
15  & a & b & c & d & e\\
\caption*{\footnotesize ...}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the very fast response!!!

Comment: @Laura don't put `longtable` in a `center` environment, it doesn't centre it, just adds spurious vertical space)

Comment: @Laura If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer (green button on the left).